# Trying to understand ''.join() taking a list in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
x = "some... random! text?!".split()

x = [''.join(char for char in string if char not in punctuation) for string 
in x]
```

I am trying to understand how this list comprehension works by replicating it in a for loop, but I'm unable to re-create it.  Here is what I currently have, but it seems incorect. What am I doing incorrectly in my for loop?

```
for string in x:
    for char in string:
        if char not in punctuation:
            ''.join(char)
```

Comment: Where are you getting `punctuation` from in both examples?

Comment: @nathancy Probably `string.punctuation`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't exactly replicate the generator argument of `join` perfectly. I would use an intermediate list:

```
result = []

for string in x:
    to_join = []
    for char in string:
        if char not in punctuation:
            to_join.append(char)
    result.append(''.join(to_join))
```

With `punctuation` as `from string import punctuation; punctuation = set(punctuation)`, it outputs

```
['some', 'random', 'text']
```

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension itself can be directly translated to the following:

```
_result = []
for string in x:
    _result.append(''.join(char for char in string if char not in punctuation))
x = _result
del _result
```

Of course, there is no intermediate variables `_result`. You use a *generator expression* inside the list comprehension, which is itself like a list-comprehension except it creates a generator. So, something like:

```
def _g():
    for char in string:
        if char not in punctuation:
            yield char
```

Putting it all together:

```
_result = []
for string in x:
    def _g():
        for char in string:
            if char not in punctuation:
                yield char
    _result.append(''.join(_g()))
del _g
x = _result
del _result
```

But again, no intermediate variables `_result` and `_g` are actually created.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a list and store the value in there, using `append`:

```
l = []
for string in x:
    s = ''
    for char in string:
        if char not in punctuation:
            s += char
    l.append(s)
```

And now:

```
print(l)
```

Is:

```
['some', 'random', 'text']
```

Comment: This doesn't output the same thing as the original code. Also, why are you joining a singular character?

Comment: Thanks for editing, but now it's essentially a less efficient version of my answer... :)

Comment: @Tomothy32 Now it is better

Comment: Appending to strings is still quite slow because strings are immutable. Anyway, it doesn't really matter in this use case.